# How to convert Boolean value from backend data into String using typescript in angular

Tags: angular, string, typescript, angular-material, boolean

My backend throws a boolean value (true/false) which have to display as a string (active/inactive).

```js
if (data['is_active'] == true) {
  data['is_active'] = 'active';
  this.is_active = data['is_active'];
} else {
  data['is_active'] = 'inactive';
  this.is_active = data['is_active'];
}
```

this is the above code written in mt typescript to check the condition, but it is not working

---

Comment: ``this.is_active="active"`` ?

Comment: Have you tried the solution?

Comment: Yes, I have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable in class, and then after fetching the data,

```js
this.status = data['is_active'] ? 'active' : 'inactive'
```

and use this variable inside html:

```html
<span>Status : {{this.status}}</span>
```

**OR directly in html:**

```html
<span>
  Status : {{data.is_active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put below line of code, will work like a charm...
Here if its return Boolean `data['is_active']` handles it and if its of type string so added fallback `data['is_active'] === 'true'`.

Happy coding ... :)

```
data['is_active'] = (data['is_active'] || data['is_active'] === 'true') ? 'active' : 'inactive';
```

Comment: you should explain your ternary expression so the OP understands why your code might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display text based on boolean value, no need to add anything in typescript, you can add condition in html:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e2ejhp)**

Try like this:

```
Status : {{data.is_active ? 'active' : 'inactive'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
if( Boolean(data['is_active']) === true){
       data['is_active'] = 'active';
            this.is_active = data['is_active'];
        }else
        {
            data['is_active'] = 'inactive';
            this.is_active = data['is_active'];
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have fetched my backend data using ID, Then I assigned a variable as status in typescript

```
 if (this.user['is_active'] == true) {
                        this.status = 'active';
                    } else {
                        this.status = 'inactive';

                    }
```

where in html, I used {{status}} to display my boolean value into string